# SharePoint PowerPivot is not refreshing

Tags: sharepoint-2010, powerpivot

PowerPivot Gallery is not refreshing.  I have tried to update the name/title, however; I got nothing from it. Is there a service that should be running that is not?  I just see an X.

**UPDATE**

I had done EVERYTHING, but nothing worked. I went [here](http://powerpivotgeek.com/troubleshooting/gallery-specific-issues/)
and still nothing. So what I did was created a new web application, and now it's back up and working.